# Where can one find exceptions thrown by Spark's Executors

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We have been getting ExecutorLostExceptions, but have been unable to determine the root cause.

Here is a simplified script that can create the error

```
filenames = "hdfs://myfile1,hdfs://myfile2"
sc.textFile(filenames).first()
```

As an experiment, when I intentionally run a spark job on 1GB of data with only 1mb of `spark.executor.memory`, the driver prints the following error message

```
16/04/28 17:28:54 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 
host.addr, partition 0,ANY, 2257 bytes)
16/04/28 17:29:28 INFO MesosSchedulerBackend: Executor lost: 4e199be7-a0bc-407d-ba70-4147e08d6c39-S5, marking slave 4e199be7-a0bc-407d-ba70-4147e08d6c39-S5 as lost
16/04/28 17:29:28 INFO MesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos slave lost: 4e199be7-a0bc-407d-ba70-4147e08d6c39-S5
16/04/28 17:29:28 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 4e199be7-a0bc-407d-ba70-4147e08d6c39-S5 on host.addr: Unknown executor exit code (256) (died from signal 128?)
16/04/28 17:29:28 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, host.addr): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4e199be7-a0bc-407d-ba70-4147e08d6c39-S5 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Unknown executor exit code (256) (died from signal 128?)
```

and after a few automated retries, the entire job fails. This happens in both Pyspark and Scala-spark.

**What are the appropriate logs I can look at to determine exactly why this executor failed?**

For this controlled case I know that running out of memory was the cause. However these and other failures with different exit codes occur on a regular basis, and then I don't know where to look or what to fix.

The places I have looked so far include

1. The spark UI running on port 4040
2. `/tmp/mesos/slaves/[slaveid]/frameworks/[frameworkid]/executors/[executorid]/runs/latest/{stderr,stdout}` on the node whose executor was "lost"
3. `/var/logs/mesos/mesos-slaves.{INFO,WARN,ERROR,FATAL}` on the failed node
4. `/tmp/spark-events/[executorid]` on the driver node

Those places have helped address some issues, but not e.g. OOM errors, and now I'm not sure where else to look.

Answer (score 0):

You can check under
$HADOOP_HOME/logs/userlogs
there you can find your logs by app id. app id can be found in hadoop cluster web ui:
<your_cluster_master_ip>:8088